# Changing Data Source from Oracle to MySQL in PowerBi

Tags: mysql, oracle, powerbi

I must change datasource of my powerbi dashboards, from an Oracle DB to a MySQL one.

My question is: apart the differences about data types, what should I know in order to avoid rework in my powerbi dashboards?

Comment: The differences between mysql and oracle are so great that it would not be possible to list them on this site.I suggest you internet search oracle vs mysql and test extensively.

Comment: The table and columns names, along with their types, must be the same. Otherwise you will have to manually modify the M code and insert fictitious rename steps to equalize the model. In general, the manual update of the M code probably is the right approach to this problem.

Comment: As per my knowledge, its a full rework. But it will save some time if you have same table and column name as you can create your measures and custom columns creating codes from the existing report.

Comment: So even if I replicate the same datasource (with same column names and homologous data types), there will be anyway rework to do?